# Do I need to update my BIOS?

Tags: firmware

I'm wanting to try Ubuntu on my PC. (Windows is getting on my nerves)

- Burnt Live Disk - check
- Insert into Drive - check
- Restart pc - check
- Click try Ubuntu without installing - check

Then I get this.

```
[0.036714] [Firmware Bug]: AMD-Vi: IOAPIC[0] not in IVRS table
[0.036792] [Firmwae Bug]: AMD-Vi: No southbridge IOAPIC found
[0.036822] AMD-Vi: Disabling interrupt remapping
```

Tried googling what I should do. But just about everywhere I look it says I need to update my BIOS. But they also say not to do so if you're not sure what you're doing.

That's why I'm here. I need a bit of help. Thank you in advance.